# Ionic and Socket.io - Method being called twice

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, socket.io

Below I have the following:

```
private setupSocketEventListeners() {
    this.socketServiceProvider.on('startTheGame', questions => {
      this.navCtrl.push(PlayGamePage, {
        questions: questions,
        isTheHost: this.isTheHost(),
        gameId: this.getGameId()
      }).then(() => {
        let index = 1
        this.navCtrl.remove(index)
      })
    })

    this.socketServiceProvider.on('updatePlayersInGame', players => {
      players.forEach(player => {
        this.players.push(player)
      })
    })

    this.socketServiceProvider.on('playerLeft', playerName => {
      this.players.pop()
    })

    this.socketServiceProvider.on('playerJoined', player => {
      this.players.push({ name: player })
    })

    this.socketServiceProvider.on('hostLeft', () => {
      if (!this.isTheHost()) {
        this.alertCtrl.create({
          message: 'The host left the game',
          buttons: [{
            text: 'Ok'
          }]
        }).present()
      }

      this.socketServiceProvider.emit('leaveGame', {
        gameId: this.getGameId(),
        playerName: this.getPlayerName()
      })
    })
  }
```

Now this is called in an ionViewDidLoad lifecycle hook. The problem I am facing is when I get to this page, I may hit the back button. So to deal with that I do the following (this is also called in inViewDidLoad)

```
this.navbar.backButtonClick = () => {
      this.navCtrl.pop()
      this.socketServiceProvider.emit('leaveGame', {
        gameId: this.getGameId(),
        playerName: this.getPlayerName()
      })
    }
```

So this will remove the HostGamePage that was added to the stack, or so I think it would. When I go back to the HostGamePage and I click the start game button, it calls the 'this.navCtrl.push(PlayGamePage' event twice, or how every many times I went back to the page after going back. Now, my socket event is not emitting twice but the actual page is executing the code twice. I cannot figure out why and what I am doing wrong but I am completely stuck now

I did overcome this problem by doing `this.app.getActiveNav().setRoot(PlayGamePage, {})` but this broke all the navigation in my application.

Comment: Have you tried adding `this.socketServiceProvider.disconnect()` to `ionViewWillUnload` ??

Comment: The issue was with my startTheGame socket listener. Had to move it out otherwise it was being instantiated twice